# White border around text covers background color

Tags: html, css, webkit, printing-web-page

I am working on a set of HTML reports that need to be printed. Everything looks OK on the screen, but a white box surrounds all of the text elements when the page is printed.

Here is a screen shot of the page on screen:
[image: screen shot of the page on screen]

Here is a screen shot of a PDF printed using the system print dialog:
[image: screen shot of a PDF printed using the system print dialog]

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css" media="all"/>
        </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
        <div id="menu">
            <b>Menu</b><br>
            HTML<br>
            CSS<br>
            JavaScript</div>
        <div id="content">
            Content goes here</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
@media print
{
    /* Hides elements on page when printed */
    .nonPrinting
    {
        display: none;
    }
    /* Forces the background colors / images to display when printing */
    body
    {
        -webkit-print-color-adjust : exact;
    }
}

#container
{
    width:500px;
}

#menu
{
    background-color:#FFD700;
    height:200px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
}
#content
{
    background-color:#EEEEEE;
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
    float:left;
}
```

The pages are running inside of a node-webkit application.

Comment: For me it's running just fine. Maybe it's a browser/web server issue?

Comment: Did you use the "Print Using System Dialog ... (Ctrl+Shift+P)" option when printing?

Comment: ctrl + p did it for me. os: win7x64, chrome 28. output format: pdf

Comment: The page lives inside a node-webkit application, so that capability isn't available.

Comment: Maybe you want to post a link then?

Comment: The behavior is the same for me when doing Ctrl+Shift+P from Chrome 28 on Windows7x64.

Comment: Again, if you add a link, we can take a detailed look at the problem.

Comment: [App Code]https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67437265/webkit/app.nw
[Node-webkit]https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/How-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps#windows-1

Comment: So there's no online source available?

Comment: Source for what? node-webkit? That's available from the github link above (along with binaries). The source for the application files are in app.nw (which is a .zip file renamed to merge with node-webkit).

Comment: No, I mean you should offer the whole page online. So that I/we can take a look at it live.

Comment: @StefanSurkamp Here is the [site](http://barlow.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/)

Comment: Thanks. Now take a look at my edited post below. Looks just fine. Maybe its a driver issue?

Comment: @StefanSurkamp Yes, it looks like it was a driver issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried assigning a specific background-color on these elements?

Try

```
background-color : transparent;
```

or

```
background-color: #FFD700;
```

on the child elements of `#menu`

**EDIT**

This is how the 'printed' pdf looks like for me:

[image: pdf at my computer]

**EDIT:**

Maybe it's a driver issue?

Comment: What elements are those? The innerHTML?

Comment: I thought about explicitly assigning classes to all children of `#menu`... thus for `<b>Menu</b><br>
            HTML<br>
            CSS<br>
            JavaScript`

Comment: I added a <div class="innerText"> around the children and set those CSS properties with no success.

Comment: I rather thought of directly assigning the class to an element, e.g. `<div class="menuClass">Menu</div>` and the following CSS: `.menuClass { font-weight: bold; background-color: transparent; /* or #FFD700 */`

Comment: I tried the suggested code with no success. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Yes, it looks like a driver issue. The page printed fine on another PC in the office.